# Not sure why while loop works different when using scanf

Tags: c

I'm new in the journey of learning C and to my knowledge, I knew that while loop would run forever if someone gives condition such as `while (1 == 1)` it would become a forever loop.

But While reading from a book I noticed a code such as

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char a;
    int started = 0;
    puts("Scanning\n");
    while (scanf("%s[^\n]",&a) == 1)
    {
        if (a >= 65 && a <= 90)
        {
            printf("Char is capital\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not cap.\n");
        }

    }
    puts("Done\n");
    return 0;


}
```

Command line => `char.exe < file.txt`

It takes input from stdin but scanf returns the number of argument i.e 1 so the condition should become while `(1 == 1)`

But why this is not a forever loop and exists after reading the file?

Thanks

Comment: What is `a`? You should flesh out the code posted so that it is a [mcve]

Comment: Read the [documentation of scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). It can return more than just the arg count

Comment: Given that you are comparing `a` to an integer, I presume it is integer. Then reading a string into it definitely should not work. Neither in loop nor outside of it.

Comment: replace `scanf("%s[^\n]",&a)` by `scanf(" %c",&a)` (notice the space in the format), also replace 65 by 'A' and 90 by 'Z'

Comment: you could use `isupper()` to test if a character is upper case rather than using those magic numbers.

Comment: Your `scanf` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your format string indicates you are trying to read a line in each iteration. You need more memory than a single character. Trying to read a file with many characters in a single char memory will crash your program. Try a bigger buffer instead. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
char a;
...
while (scanf("%s[^\n]",&a) == 1)
```

your format is invalid because dedicated to a string while you want to read only a char, so you will write out of the char at least for the ending null char producing an undefined behavior

do

```
char a;
...
while (scanf(" %c",&a) == 1)
```

and notice the space in the format, remove it if you want to manage all the characters

In

> ```
>  if (a >= 65 && a <= 90)
> ```

it is wrong to use ASCII code, this is not readable and not compatible with non ASCII

you can do

```
if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
```

or better use *isupper* (`<ctype.h>`) because it is not guaranty than the uppercase letters are consecutive

Your *printf* can be replaced by *puts* removing the \n in the string, or a *fputs*, is is useless to have *printf* to print a simple string (without % and arg)

> But why this is not a forever loop and exists after reading the file?

*scanf* does not return 1 on EOF, so the loop stops on EOF, about *scanf* family  :

> These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

Comment: All absolutely true, but not responsive to the question actually posed.

Answer (score 1):

> But why this is not a forever loop and exists after reading the file?

It will loop indefinitely only if `scanf` returns 1 every time it is called.  The loop terminates the first time that function returns a different result.<sup>*</sup>

`scanf`'s return value conveys the number of input fields ***successfully*** scanned and assigned, and under some circumstances also conveys information about I/O errors.  In particular, `scanf` will return the value of macro `EOF` if it reaches the end of the input before matching any fields.  `EOF` is unequal to 1.

---

<sup>*</sup>Provided that the program's behavior is well defined.  *Your* program's is not, for reasons described in comments and another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function scanf returns the following value:

- `>0`  The number of items converted and assigned successfully.
- 0 — No item was assigned.
- <0 — Read error encountered or end-of-file (EOF) reached before any
  assignment was made.

Answer (score 0):

`&a` indicates that you are trying to read a whole line in a stack variable.

> But why this is not a forever loop and exists after reading the file?

Trying to read a file in a stack variable will cause stack smashing and your program would crash.

Look for different storage types and memory management in C on internet. `a` is a character variable allocated on the program stack and is only suppose to store one character. If you take it's address and try to put more data then it will corrupt adjacent stack memory/variables until OS detects that and kills your program. Your format indicates it will read a whole line i.e. until new line.
 `scanf` will still return 1 but it will try to store that line in the address of `a`.

Did you run it like:

```
cat <your file>| ./a.out
```

Allocate a big enough buffer like `char a[4096];` and pass `a` as

```
while(scanf("%s[^\n]", a) == 1)
```

Note now `a` is an array now and does not need a `&` in front. Your loop will still exit but on EOF when the file finishes. Try to use a file smaller than 4 Kb side for the worst case if new line does not appear until 4Kb.

Provisions for reading a bigger file/lines seem out of scope of your experiment.

**Working code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

char a[4096];
int started = 0;
puts("Scanning\n");
while (scanf("%s[^\n]", a) == 1)
{
    if (a >= 65 && a <= 90)
    {
        printf("Char is capital\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not cap.\n");
    }

}
puts("Done\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a letter the condition `(1==1)` becomes true and the body of `while` loop is iterated.

After iteration of `while` loop it goes for next letter. `scanf` waits till you enter next character.

Again condition `(1==1)` is satisfied.

This loop is an indefinite loop and you could go on entering letters and you would never reach the `puts` statement.